# Как можно сверстать такой элемент xml?

Tags: android, xml, view, android-view

[image]

Только начал изучать верстку в xml. Не могу сверстать "хвост" у view.

Comment: как вариант можно без хвоста делать, будет тоже нормально

Comment: Это, конечно, хорошо, но все-таки хотелось бы понять и научится тому, как это можно сделать.

Comment: мне кажется это к дизайнерам, вручную такое сомневаюсь что можно сделать быстро и просто, легче если дизайнер даст вам svg и вы его будете использовать

Comment: Бэкграунд у вьюхи либо картинка 9toPatch .9.png либо , как уже сказали в векторе svg. Ну тут мы видим две аьюхи если что drawable_left и deawable_right.  Можно загуглить как делается чат ресайклер вью , и посмотреть по примерам как делают такие вью элементы.

Comment: в данном случае все изображение, вместе с хвостом - простая картинка, которая используется, как бэкграунд для лэйаута.